# Does removing the pistil from an Amaryllis flower extend the life of the bloom?

Tags: flowers, flowering, bulbs, amaryllis

I have several Amaryllis bulbs starting to bloom. Will removing the pistil extend the life of the bloom?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any reason why it would with an amaryllis or any other flower. Lilies,  though, will last slightly longer if the pollen is carefully removed because the pollen falls easily and can cause damage to the flower and therefore shorten the bloom's life, but it's not necessary to remove the stamens or pistil. Lilies and Amaryllis do not belong to the same Families of plants; Amaryllis do not seem to have the same problem with pollen.

Comment: The first one had 4 flowers open within a day, I cut pistils from two as a test ( what could go wrong ?).

Comment: @blacksmith37 in that case - we’re looking forward to your own answer with the results of the experiment!

Comment: Pardon the delay : I remember no noticeable difference.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a flower, any flower, is to get fertilized. Removing the stamen (pollen carriers = male) will stop the flowers from getting fertilized. Flowers that do not get fertilized keep trying, therefore they 'live' longer.

The pollen does NOT damage the flower. Just stain your clothes.

Comment: Welcome Dutch Girl, do have any reference for this?